# expression in English

Tags: grammar

> I **lived in** Victory Street.

vs

> I **lived out in** Victory Street.

What are the difference between the above two sentences? 
The second one which I read it on the internet. Is it correct?

Comment: Using *out* in that contexts merely suggests that Victory Street is relatively distant from somewhere, either where the user works or lives or from the center of the city.

Answer (score 1):

***Out*** is used before a location (generally a location using *in* or *on*) to suggest distance, either from the present location or the local centre. So "out in Victory Street" (which is weird, I'd've thought it would be *on*, not *in*) could mean either Victory Street is some way away from the present location, where the speaker is now, or from the centre of the local town, neighbourhood, city, etc.

Consider the expression "out in the country"; this refers to the *countryside*, the rural areas, and they are always distant from the local centre.

Comment: Britons live *in* a street; Americans live *on* it.

Comment: Well, ***I'm British***, and I've lived on several streets in my life. Never in a street.

Comment: Interesting. The only time I've ever encountered *in* used that way is by the British: Londoners, specifically. Perhaps it is regional?

Comment: Well, when I lived in London for the first 13 years of my life, I lived on streets (or roads or lanes) then, too. We generally use *in* for neighbourhoods, estates, towns, cities, villages etc (and a village called *Victory Street* is not entirely implausible), and *on* for roads, streets, avenues, etc. There's the odd exception - if an area is named for a geographic feature you might use *on*, and for closes or crescents (particular types of streets) sometimes people use *in*. Estates particularly can use *in* or *on* a lot of the time.

Comment: @SamBC: Thank you for enlightening me. Would a "mews" be considered a street or a neighborhood? That one sticks out in my memory as having the "in" complement: e.g., "I live in Cardington Mews" ...

Comment: Ah, mews are another exception, though a less common one. You could use both. The history of the term may aid understanding of that one.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't a bad summary in this case, for the history: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mews - in terms of modern use it's a street or small collection of interconnected streets that are usually one "street" for address purposes, one lot of numbers through the whole area. They are generally set back from the main thoroughfares and afford a certain degree of quiet and privacy. Occasionally a development will be called a mews, but also have named streets within it, making it more like a (very small) neighbourhood.

Comment: Again, thanks. (And +1 for your answer, btw.) One more thing: are commercial establishments more likely to use *in* than are residences, all else being equal?

Comment: @Robusto: Not that I've ever noticed, but I can't say I've paid especial attention.